# O365 - Separate topologies

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

Let's say we have three domains: **domaina.com**, **domainb.com** and **domainc.com**.
They have no trust between them.

#### Initial situation

**Domain A:** Active Directory with 2008 R2 & Exchange 2013

**Domain B:** Active Directory with 2008 & Exchange 2007 SP2

**Domain C:** Active Directory with 2012 R2 and with Office365, OneDrive for Business & Sharepoint Online

#### Migration

They want to migrate together to one unique domain **domaind.com**: emails, accounts, Sharepoint, OD4B.

#### Questions

- Is it possible to migrate an existing Sharepoint Online to a new one into a new Office 365 ?
- About OD4B ?
- I've found cloudmigrator365 for O365-O365 migration, but it is really expensive. Is there any other solution ?
- Is it possible to migrate the different Active Directories **into the same domain** ? I mean, instead of having domaina.domaind.com and domainb.domaind.com, we should simply have domaind.com.

Thanks in advance for the help you will provide.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to migrate an existing Sharepoint Online to a new one into a new Office 365?**

It is - but you will need a 3rd party tool or write your export routine using the API's. You can manually move data by exporting documents to folders and lists to Excel, but it's tedious to both export and import.

**About OD4B ?**

It's just SharePoint - so same thing applies here.  Your less likely to have lists and other Misc. data - so if you already have documents synced locally you could just move those to your new OD4B sync folder and let that data sync up on it's own.  It's a bit more error prone and tedius than just using a tool.

**I've found cloudmigrator365 for O365-O365 migration, but it is really expensive. Is there any other solution ?**

- MetaLogix has a tool where they offer 25GB of migration data for free.
- I prefer ShareGate -it's simple, fast, and  my favorite feature is that it has PowerShell Cmdlets so you can script your entire move. It's probably the "least expensive" tool out their currently - but support is top notch.

**Is it possible to migrate the different Active Directories into the same domain ? I mean, instead of having domaina.domaind.com and domainb.domaind.com, we should simply have domaind.com.**

Yes - you can sync multiple forests/domains to same tenant.  You need to be careful however that import object don't conflict. You need to use FIM or the recently released Azure AD Connect Sync tool.